# Fragment not being replaced

Tags: android

I have a `FragmentActivity` that is supposed to swap out the front screen fragment (with buttons) to the fragment that the button points to when one is clicked.

Suppose the button that invokes `SourceListFragment` is clicked. Both `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` of `SourceListFragment` are called, but somehow the screen stays the same, i.e. the front screen fragment isn't getting replaced.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

 ...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set uncaught exception handler for thread
    // Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    mMainFrame = MainFragment.newInstance();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mMainFrame).commit();
}

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int id) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.button_sources:
                Fragment fragment = new SourceListFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTrans = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.main_screen, fragment);
                fragmentTrans.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTrans.commit();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}



public class SourceListFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnClickListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d("SOURCELIST", "SourceListFragment onCreateView\n");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sourceitem_list, viewGroup, false);

        return view;
    }


    public static SourceListFragment newInstance(BluetoothAdapter adapter) {
        SourceListFragment fragment = new SourceListFragment();
        mBTAdapter = adapter;
        return fragment;
    }

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(int id);
    }
}
```

Here's the layout:

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FFF"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/container">

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/main_screen"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="148dp">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="128dp"
                android:background="#01579b"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:paddingLeft="104dp" android:id="@+id/banner">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/button_sources"
                app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
                app:layout_heightPercent="30%"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="10%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="5%"/>
...

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_sourceitem_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
            android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndeterminate"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="#1E88E5" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You mean, replace `fragment_sourceitem_list.xml` with a dummy fragment?

Comment: I've tried a blank LinearLayout, but still the same as well. `onCreateView()` gets called - isn't onCreateView called during rendering?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've added `MainActivity.onCreate()` to clarify things. Basically id main_screen is added to id container there.

Comment: You push the frament into LinearLayout   with id main_screen . Since it's not a FrameLayout. are you sure it supposed to be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add  a Fragment into Linear layout with id main_screen, but the fragment should be added into FrameLayout.  The transitions do work in case of LinearLayout, but the newly added Fragment is  outside of the display.

Comment: I've figured out the problem. It's because I'm doing `fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.main_screen, fragment);` rather than `fragmentTrans.replace(R.id.container, fragment);`

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem. Please accept my answer  as the reward for helping you to figure out the problem :)